# access vba click buttons refresh form but trigger click event do not refresh the form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, refresh

I have 2 buttons to filter / unfilter a subform. Event codes (private) are calling a public function:

I can click buttons to filter / unfilter, it is working well.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim PartCalendarSubHeaderFilterOn As Boolean

Private Sub imgClearFilter_Click()
    PartCalendarSubHeaderFilterOn = False
    UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
End Sub

Private Sub imgFavoriteFilter_Click()
    PartCalendarSubHeaderFilterOn = True
    UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
End Sub

Public Sub UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter()
    If PartCalendarSubHeaderFilterOn Then
        PartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
    Else
        PartCalendarSubHeaderClearFilter
    End If
    Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub PartCalendarSubHeaderClearFilter()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "... "
    Me!frmPartCalendarSubHeaders.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub

Private Sub PartCalendarSubHeaderFilter()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "... "
    Me!frmPartCalendarSubHeaders.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

From another form current event, I want to refresh the part calendar by calling the update filter sub by calling the public method:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ...
    'update part calendar
    Form_frmPartCalendarSub.UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
    Me.Parent!frmPartCalendarSub.Requery
End Sub
```

When I follow line by line in debug mode, I can see it goes through the exact same code as when I click on filter / unfilter buttons, goes through the lines

```
Me!frmPartCalendarSubHeaders.Form.RecordSource = sql
```

and

```
Me.Requery
```

but the subform is not refreshing as expected.

Interresting thing: in debug mode, if I reset once just after entering code line

```
Public Sub UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter()
```

Then it works correctly: I can filter using buttons, and when I select another record it refreshes correctly, according to the filter selected.

Have you ever encountered this king of problem? What should I correct to make the code work from start, without having to break from debug mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
Form_frmPartCalendarSub.UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
```

by

```
Forms("frmPartCalendarSub").UpdatePartCalendarSubHeaderFilter
```

First command doesn't guarantee that code executed in correct instance of form. It would be better to avoid using direct calls of Form's class methods, it may lead to unexpected results.